# calculate value based on other column values with some step for rows of other columns

Tags: pandas, row, shift, rolling-computation

total beginner here. If my question is irrelevant, apologies in advance, I'll remove it. So, I have a question : using pandas, I want to calculate an evolution ratio for a week data compared with the ***previous*** rolling 4 weeks mean data.

`df['rolling_mean_fourweeks'] = df.rolling(4).mean().round(decimals=1)`

[image: shape of my df random data]

from here I wanna create a new column for the evolution ratio based on the week data compared with the row of the rolling mean at the previous week.
what is the best way to go here? (I don't have big data) I have tried unsuccessfully with ***.shift()*** but am very foreign to .shift()... I should get NAN for week 3 (fourth week) and ~47% for fifth week.
Any suggestion for retrieving the value at row with step -1?

Thanks and have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea about using `shift` can perfectly work. The `shift(x)` function simply shifts a series (a full column in your case) of `x` steps.

A simple way to check if the `rolling_mean_fourweeks` is a good predictor can be to shift `Column1` and then check how it differs from `rolling_mean_fourweeks`:

```py
df['column1_shifted'] = df['Column1'].shift(-1)
df['rolling_accuracy'] = ((df['column1_shifted']-df['rolling_mean_fourweeks'])
                            /df['rolling_mean_fourweeks'])
```

resulting in:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! did that with .shift() in the formula directly (skipd creating column_shifted)! it works!

Comment: sure, I just  added it to explicitly show the output of the function :)